# EPrints 500 Internal Server Error when Add a new document from existing record

Tags: perl, repository, http-status-code-500, citations

**EPrints Release:  3.3.15**

I've been stucked **cannot upload new docs** for my eprints' existing record.

I CAN upload new docs if I create new Record (from Manage Deposit menu)

I've checked this troubleshooting URL https://wiki.eprints.org/w/Troubleshooting#System_gives_a_.22500_Internal_Error.22_when_viewing_advanced_search_or_submitting_a_document

*Quote*

> System gives a "500 Internal Error" when viewing advanced search or
>   submitting a document
>
> Possible cause: No Subjects, Bug in code.
>
> Solution: Run generate_subjects
>
> If this fails: Look at your apache error log for clues. If reporting a
>   bug, include the errors from the apache error log (often, but now
>   always, found at /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log)

But I CANNOT FIND the damn **generate_subjects** function/url/else...
I've googled around but nothing

Thanks for any helps/solutions

Comment: I have no clue what this is about, but have you looked at the apache log?

Comment: I check the log using command: ```tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log``` and upload new docs, but I dont see any errors generated..

Only some kind of weird lines like :

```
/usr/share/eprints/archives/ub/var/last_changed.timestamp has been modified since the repository config was loaded: reloading!
/usr/share/eprints/archives/ub/var/last_changed.timestamp has been modified since the repository config was loaded: reloading!
/usr/share/eprints/archives/ub/var/last_changed.timestamp has been modified since the repository config was loaded: reloading!
```